# Program is saying all my valid inputs are invalid (REGEX code Issue maybe?)

Tags: java, regex, matching

Question Given:

Prompt the user to input a name. The name may have a salutation, and valid salutations are “Mr” and “Ms”. Next, after a single whitespace character (if there was a salutation) is the first name. After another whitespace character, there may or may not be a middle initial, which is a single uppercase letter which may or may not have a “.” after it. Finally, after another whitespace, the last name is given. The first and last name will both start with uppercase letters. Determine, using a single regex check, whether or not the input name is valid. If it is valid, print the first and last name. If not, let the user know.

Example:

Program: Please enter a name:

User: Mr Ryan D Scott

Program: Ryan Scott

---

Program: Please enter a name:

User: Mr Ryan D. Scott

Program: Ryan Scott

---

Program: Please enter a name:

User: Ryan Scott

Program: Ryan Scott

---

Program: Please enter a name:

User: Mr Ryan Scott

Program: Ryan Scott

---

Program: Please enter a name:

User: Ryan D Scott

Program: Ryan Scott

---

Program: Please enter a name:

User: Captain Fluffyface the 6th

Program: Invalid name.

---

Program: Please enter a name:

User: Spongebob Squarepants

Program: Spongebob Squarepants

---

I need help fixing the regex expression and having it output the first and last name inputted only as shown in the examples above (updated code)

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.util.regex.Matcher;
 import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class lab2q2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {      

    String RegularExp = "((Mr|Ms))?[A-Z][a-z]+([A-Z]([a-z]+\\.))?([A-Z](a-z)+)"; 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(RegularExp);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i< 11; i++)
    {
            System.out.println("Please enter a name: ");

            String inputString = keyboard.nextLine(); 
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString );
            if (!matcher.matches()) 
            {
                System.out.println("Name: " + inputString);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid name.");
            }
    }

    keyboard.close(); 

   }// end method main
}// end class
```

Comment: Seems your regex doesn't account for the spaces between names.

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: `Captain Fluffyface the 6th` fails cause you didn't include numbers in your regex,  `fawzi qaisi ` fails cause you specified that first letter of name must be capital...

Comment: I think your last capturing also meant to be [a-z] not (a-z). And yeah no accounting for white spaces.

Comment: The examples given are to show you what should pass and what shouldn't pass. And I am required to use regex to solve the problem

Comment: Would adding \\s+ allow it to read spaces?

Comment: Use online regex testing tool to fine tune your regex using examples given.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to add `Pattern`.

```
  import java.util.*;

  public class lab2q2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String RegularExp = "((Mr|Ms))?[A-Z][a-z]+([A-Z]([a-z]+\\.))?([A-Z](a-z)+)"; 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(RegularExp);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



    for(int i = 0; i< 11; i++)
    {
            System.out.println("Please enter a name: ");

            String inputString = keyboard.nextLine(); 
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString );
            if(!matcher.matches()) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + inputString);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid name.");
            }
    }

    keyboard.close(); 

    }// end method main
}//
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!!!!!! Now how can I get it to only output the fist and last name inputted, and not the "Mr or Ms" and middle initial?

Comment: for System.out.println("Name: " + inputString); what would I need to change to just output Fawzi Qaisi is the input was Mr Fawzi Qaisi or Fawzi A. Qaisi?

Comment: congratulations you fed the help vampire ...

Comment: why my answer down voted can I know??

Answer (score -1):

- Your last (a-z)+ should be [a-z]+
- You don't allow spaces, and you didn't make . optional in the initial
- The initial should be [A-Z] not [A-Z][a-z]+
- You don't match line start and end

Corrected

```
^(?:(?:Mr|Ms)\ )?([A-Z][a-z]+)\ (?:[A-Z]\.?\ )?([A-Z][a-z]+)$
```

Answer (score -1):

(Edited) I checked your examples with the following regexp

```
((Mr |Ms ))?([A-z][a-z]*[ ]?)([A-Z]?(\\.){1}[ ]?)?([A-z]{1}[a-z]*[ ]?)
```

Also, dunno the domain of possible values you'll get but you should take into account some other possible characters on names (`Ms Scarlett O'Hara` would be invalid).
For those kind of names, you could use

```
((Mr |Ms ))?([A-Z][A-Za-z']*[ ]?)([A-Z]?(\.){1}[ ]?)?([A-z]{1}[A-Za-z']*[ ]?)
```

Comment: When I entered this into my code it said "Invalid escape sequence"

Comment: Edited the answer. Sorry :) P.S. I used Regex Tester on IntelliJ to check the regexp. You could add a plugin to your preferred IDE as well